# How find vectors after spinning counterclockwise?

Tags: physics

$\vec A$ has the magnitude $13.5$ m and is angled $68.0°$ counterclockwise from the positive direction of the x axis of an xy coordinate system. Also, $\vec B$ $= (11.5 m)i + (7.15 m)j$ on that same coordinate system. We now rotate the system counterclockwise about the origin by $20.0°$ to form an $x'y'$ system.

(a) On this new system, what are $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ in unit-vector notation?

I don't understand what needs to be done.

Am I supposed to:

$13.5$ times $68$ times cos minus $20$ ?

$\sqrt 11.5^2 + 7.15 ^2 - 20$?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?  Show the original and new axes and $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ relative to the original axes.  What is the angle of $\vec A$ from the new $x$ axis?  The magnitude stays the same, but you need to assess the components along the new axes. For $\vec B$ you need to compute its angle from the old axes and then its angle from the new axes.

Comment: I don't understand. How could I draw a picture if I don't have any x,y coordinates? How do I determine angles and components and other angles?

Comment: You can draw the axes, and you can draw $\vec A$ by following the directions.  Find an angle $68^\circ$ counterclockwise from $+x$ and draw a vector of length $13.5$.  You can imagine swinging a compass.  You can also calculate the components with $x=r \cos \theta, y=r \sin \theta.  You have the components for $\vec B$.  You will need to find its angle from the arctangent.